# Reset required fields - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have some fields that I'm requiring depending on which button is clicked.  The behavior I'm seeing though is not what I would expect nor desire.  When I click one of the buttons, it sets the required fields as I'd like, but then if I click another button, it doesn't reset them for some reason.

Code is below.  Thanks for any help you can provide:

```
function makeAllRequired() {
        $("#SomeForm").validate({
            rules: {
                StartDate: {
                    required: true,
                    date: true
                },
                Name: {
                    required: true
                }

            },
            errorElement: "div"
        });
    }

    function makeSomeRequired() {
        $("#SomeForm").validate({
            rules: {
                StartDate: {
                    required: true,
                    date: true
                }
            },
            errorElement: "div"
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#SomeButtonOne").click(function () {
            makeAllRequired();
            $("#SomeForm").attr("action", "/here/there");
            $("#SomeForm").submit();
        });
$("#SomeButtonTwo").click(function () {
            makeSomeRequired();
            $("#SomeForm").attr("action", "/here/elsewhere");
            $("#SomeForm").submit();
        });
});
```

Comment: can we please see the html as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reseting the form before setting new required items: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/resetForm

Comment: can't seem to get that to work.  I've tried putting in the validate().resetForm() method in my two functions that do the validation and it's not changing the behavior.  I've tried putting it before and after the validation logic, neither work.  When I put it before, it just allows the form to submit, when I put it after, it doesn't reset the validation for the next button click.

Comment: sorry, was that a question?  If so, I dont' understand it :/

Comment: Sorry. Can you throw the example with HTML in to jsfiddle.net and share it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but try removing the rules first before you apply new ones

```
function makeAllRequired() {
    $("#SomeForm").rules("remove");
    $("#SomeForm").validate({
        rules: {
            StartDate: {
                required: true,
                date: true
            },
            Name: {
                required: true
            }

        },
        errorElement: "div"
    });
}

function makeSomeRequired() {
    $("#SomeForm").rules("remove");
    $("#SomeForm").validate({
        rules: {
            StartDate: {
                required: true,
                date: true
            }
        },
        errorElement: "div"
    });
}
```